# Load URLs into UIWebView from NSArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I have created a table view with navigation controller.
I want to link table data with `UIWebView` so that when I click on a particular table data it will open its respective URL.

How can I do this?

Comment: -1 -- doesn't look like you put any research into this question before asking; also, http://whathaveyoutried.com ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you have array of URLs

```
   NSArray* aryURL =[[NSURL alloc]initWithObjects:@"WWW.google.com",@"www.yahoo.com",@"www.facebook.com",nil];
```

now in tableView DataSource methods

```
  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
       return [aryURL count];
  }


  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
     if (cell == nil) 
     {
          cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
     }
     cell.textLabel.text = [aryURL objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     return cell;
 }


 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     WebViewController *webObj = [[WebViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];
     webObj.stringURl = [aryURL objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:webObj animated:YES];
 }
```

Now in **WebViewController** class you have to create **stingURL** file and @property @synthesise it and in **ViewDidLoad** you can give stringURL to WebView object as URL string.

Comment: -(void) initUIWebView
{
    
   CGRect webframe=CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,320.0, 450.0);
    UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:webframe];
   

    [webview1 setDelegate:self];
   
     NSArray* urla =[[NSURL alloc]initWithObjects:@"WWW.google.com",@"www.fb.com",nil];  
    
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlas];
    
    

    NSURLRequest *requestobj=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webview1 loadRequest:requestobj];
    [self.view addSubview:webview1];
}





i used this code but error coming in the array of url line as NSURL not declared

Comment: and how to create StringURL file??